# How do I resolve sys.path differences in Python and IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython

I am running into pathing issues with some scripts that I wrote to test parsers I've written. It would appear that Python (27 and 3) both do not act like IronPython when it comes to using the current working directory as part of sys.path. As a result my inner package pathings do not work.

This is my package layout.

```
MyPackage
  __init__.py
  _test
      __init__.py
      common.py
  parsers
     __init__.py
     _test
          my_test.py
```

I am attempting to call the scripts from within the MyPackage directory.

Command Line Statements:

python ./parsers/_test/my_test.py

ipy ./parsers/_test/my_test.py

The import statement located in my my_test.py file is.

```
from _test.common import TestClass
```

In the python scenario I get ONLY the MyPackage/parsers/_test directory appended to sys.path so as a result MyPackage cannot be found. In the IronPython scenario both the MyPackage/parsers/_test directory AND MyPackage/ is in sys.path. I could get the same bad reference if I called the test from within the _test directory (it would have no idea about MyPackage). Even if i consolidated the test files into the _test directory I would still have this pathing issue.

I should note, that I just tested and if i did something like

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
```

It will load correctly. But I would have to do this for every single file.

Is there anyway to fix this kind of pathing issue without doing the following.

A. Appending a relative pathing for sys.path in every file.

B. Appending PATH to include MyPackage (I do not want my package as part of the python "global" system pathing)

Thanks alot for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

- Use the environment variable PYTHONPATH and include .
- Add it to your sys.path at the beginning of your program

> ```
> import sys.path
> sys.path.append('.')
> ```

- If you need to import a relative path dynamically you can always do something like

> ```
> import somemodule
> import sys
> dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(somemodule.__file__))
> sys.path.append(dirname)
> ```

Comment: This definitely works. It kind of violates my restriction A. (i'd have to do this for every file.) But is this some kind of standard practice? I can't imagine other people don't have this issue as well... Or they've designed it so that it isn't an issue. Or i guess they're appending the path to their package in the environments PYTHONPATH

Comment: You could just add the path in your system wide site.py?